# What are the academic names for the left and right operands in binary relational operator?

Tags: operators, relational, operand, operands

Relational operators such as <, >=, == are often not bidirectional. What are the correct names for the operands to these operators? An example from an non-relational operator, division, would be the operand names divisor and dividend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Comparand*** for either operand.

An operand of an equality/inequality is referred to as a *comparand* in some mathematical, linguistic & computing contexts. Google 'comparand' with 'math', 'linguistics', 'ibm', 'intel', 'microsoft' or 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

(It's not in the OED or Merriam-Webster. It's in the Wiktionary.)

(For 'linguistics' Google even finds a [*comparee* & *comparand*](https://books.google.ca/books?isbn=1847693121).)

Answer (score -2):

Comparand is the word used for operator and Comparanda is the word used for things being compared. But the most practiced word is still Comparison Operator.